# Taxonomy images display in different view rows

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a vocabulary that has an image field. To access this field in views, I added a relationship and then added the field in the fields section.

However, I have multiple terms and each term creates a new row... As this is highly undesirable, I would like to know how to fix it without making and embedding an additional view.

Comment: `without making and embedding an additional view` I'm afraid there is no answer for this.

Comment: Aww... That shucks... Okay, custom text field with embed view code, here we come! Thanks @NoSssweat

Comment: OR... you could just use [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), up to you.

Comment: no, that will only embed it before or after your view and not as a field for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Received answer from [@Lendude](https://www.drupal.org/u/lendude) on drupal forums [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2848245#comment-11952765):

> Yeah, adding relationships will add rows, that is the way of SQL
>   queries.
>
> If you enable aggregation and then group the results on the right
>   column, that works in some use cases (make sure to set/save the column
>   for your image field or you will run into this [#2815881: Switching on
>   aggregation on generates fatal "Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column](https://www.drupal.org/node/2815881)" SQL error when using multi-column Fields) Using the 'rendered
>   entity' field with a specific view mode can work. This would possibly
>   allow you to remove the relationship from the View itself.